# don't work submit in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have this code code of submit form:

```
$('.nav_step ul li').live('click', function(event){
    $( "#"+where_it ).submit();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="row nav_step">
    <ul>
        <li class="first">
            <a href="/~162/appsite/requirement/index.html">
                <span class="left_bg">
                    <span class="right_bg">
                        <span class="center_bg">
                            <span class="namber_box">1</span>&nbsp;Requirements
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="/~162/appsite/profile/index.html">
                <span class="left_bg">
                    <span class="right_bg">
                        <span class="center_bg">
                            <span class="namber_box">2</span>&nbsp;Profile
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="/~162/appsite/assets/index.html">
                <span class="left_bg">
                    <span class="right_bg">
                        <span class="center_bg">
                            <span class="namber_box">3</span>&nbsp;Assets
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
            <a href="/~162/appsite/liability/index.html">
                <span class="left_bg">
                    <span class="right_bg">
                        <span class="center_bg">
                            <span class="namber_box">4</span>&nbsp;Liabilities
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="/~162/appsite/third/index.html">
                <span class="left_bg">
                    <span class="right_bg">
                        <span class="center_bg">
                            <span class="namber_box">5</span>&nbsp;Third&nbsp;Parties
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="/~162/appsite/compliance/index.html">
                <span class="left_bg">
                    <span class="right_bg">
                        <span class="center_bg">
                            <span class="namber_box">6</span>&nbsp;Compliance
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="/~162/appsite/document/index.html">
                <span class="left_bg">
                    <span class="right_bg">
                        <span class="center_bg">
                            <span class="namber_box">7</span>&nbsp;Documents
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="last">
            <a href="/~162/appsite/document/result.html">
                <span class="left_bg">
                    <span class="right_bg">
                        <span class="center_bg">
                            <span class="namber_box">8</span>&nbsp;Submit
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<form class="form-vertical" id="client-liability-form" action="/~162/appsite/liability/update.html" method="post">
<div style="display:none"><input type="hidden" value="ccc127985bc916e7ee507b4a238173097edf2338" name="YII_CSRF_TOKEN"></div>        <fieldset>
            <div class="large-15 columns button_holder">
                <div class="indent_holder_2">
                    <strong class="btn_previous movePrev"><a href="#">Previous</a></strong>
                    <strong class="btn_save moveSave"><a href="#">Save</a></strong>
                    <strong class="btn_next moveNext"><a href="#">Next</a></strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="itemsHolder" class="liability">

<div class="large-15 columns box_bg_holder_2 iner_2 liabilityBlock" rel="0">
    <div class="indent_holder">
        <div class="row indent_5">
            <div class="large-3 columns">
                <div class="row_label_2">
                    <label></label>
                </div>
                <div class="row_input">
                    <select class="select_box_2 selectLiability" name="ApplicationLiability[0][item_type]" id="ApplicationLiability_0_item_type">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Property Loan</option>
<option value="1">Credit Card</option>
<option value="2">Car Lease</option>
<option value="3">Personal Loan</option>
<option value="4">Other</option>
</select><span class="required_field_text" id="ApplicationLiability_item_type_em_" style="display: none"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="large-3 columns">
                <div class="row_label">
                    <label for="ApplicationLiability_address">Address</label>                </div>
                <div class="row_input">
                    <input class="input_box_2" name="ApplicationLiability[0][address]" id="ApplicationLiability_0_address" type="text" maxlength="255"><span class="required_field_text" id="ApplicationLiability_address_em_" style="display: none"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <div class="row_label_2">
                    <label></label>
                </div>
                <div class="row_input top_margin">
                    <div class="row_input_4">
                        <span class="ownership_text" rel="0"><a href="#">Ownership</a></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row_input_4">
                        <strong class="hint_holder iner">
                            <a href="#" tabindex="-9999">Monthly Payment</a>
                        </strong>
                        <input class="input_box_2 maskMoney monthly_payment" name="ApplicationLiability[0][monthly]" id="ApplicationLiability_0_monthly" type="text" value="$ 0"><span class="required_field_text" id="ApplicationLiability_monthly_em_" style="display: none"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row_input_4">
                        <strong class="hint_holder">
                            <a href="#" tabindex="-9999">Limit</a>
                        </strong>
                        <input class="input_box_2 maskMoney limit" name="ApplicationLiability[0][limit]" id="ApplicationLiability_0_limit" type="text" value="$ 0"><span class="required_field_text" id="ApplicationLiability_limit_em_" style="display: none"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row_input_4">
                        <strong class="hint_holder">
                            <a href="#" tabindex="-9999">Balance</a>
                        </strong>
                        <input class="input_box_2 maskMoney balance" name="ApplicationLiability[0][balance]" id="ApplicationLiability_0_balance" type="text" value="$ 0"><span class="required_field_text" id="ApplicationLiability_balance_em_" style="display: none"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="large-3 columns indent_top">
                <strong class="btn_delete liability"><a href="#">Delete</a></strong>
                                    <strong class="btn_add_more liability"><a>Add More</a></strong>
                            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-3 columns">
                <div class="row_label_2">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="large-3 columns">
                <div class="row_input_2">
                    <div class="row_label">
                        <label class="line" for="ApplicationLiability_bsb">BSB</label>                    </div>
                    <div class="row_input">
                        <input class="input_box_2" name="ApplicationLiability[0][bsb]" id="ApplicationLiability_0_bsb" type="text" maxlength="255"><span class="required_field_text" id="ApplicationLiability_bsb_em_" style="display: none"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row_input_2">
                    <div class="row_label double_width iner">
                        <label for="ApplicationLiability_account_number">Account Number</label>                    </div>
                    <div class="row_input">
                        <input class="input_box_2" name="ApplicationLiability[0][account_number]" id="ApplicationLiability_0_account_number" type="text" maxlength="255"><span class="required_field_text" id="ApplicationLiability_account_number_em_" style="display: none"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="large-3 columns">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ownership_block" style="display: none;">
                            <div class="row indent_5">
                    <div class="row_label">
                        Tom Tomas                    </div>
                    <div class="row_input">
                        <input type="text" value="50" name="Ownership[0][118][percent]" id="Ownership_0_118_percent"><span>%</span>
                        <input type="hidden" value="118" name="Ownership[0][118][applicant_id]" id="Ownership_0_118_applicant_id">                    </div>
                </div>
                            <div class="row indent_5">
                    <div class="row_label">
                        Tom Tomas                    </div>
                    <div class="row_input">
                        <input type="text" value="50" name="Ownership[0][125][percent]" id="Ownership_0_125_percent"><span>%</span>
                        <input type="hidden" value="125" name="Ownership[0][125][applicant_id]" id="Ownership_0_125_applicant_id">                    </div>
                </div>
                            <div class="row indent_5">
                    <div class="row_label">
                                             </div>
                    <div class="row_input">
                        <input type="text" value="0" name="Ownership[0][126][percent]" id="Ownership_0_126_percent"><span>%</span>
                        <input type="hidden" value="126" name="Ownership[0][126][applicant_id]" id="Ownership_0_126_applicant_id">                    </div>
                </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn_save">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>            </div>
            <div class="large-15 columns box_bg_holder">
                <div class="indent_holder iner">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="large-6 columns">
                            <div class="row_label_2">
                                <label for="ApplicationLiability_monthly_exp">What are your current Monthly expenses?</label>                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="large-6 columns">
                            <div class="row_input">
                                <div class="row_input_4 none">
                                    <strong class="total_price"></strong>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row_input_4">
                                    <input class="input_box_2 maskMoney monthly_payment" name="ApplicationLiability[0][monthly_exp]" id="ApplicationLiability_0_monthly_exp" type="text" value="$ 0"><span class="required_field_text" id="ApplicationLiability_monthly_exp_em_" style="display: none"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row_input_4 none">
                                    <strong class="btn_help_box">
                                        <a href="#">help</a>
                                        <span class="help_box">There Will Be any written comment</span>
                                    </strong>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="large-1 columns">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="large-15 columns box_bg_holder_2 iner_4">
                <div class="indent_holder">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="large-6 columns">
                            <div class="row_label_2">
                                <label></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="large-6 columns">
                            <div class="row_label_2">
                                <label></label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row_input">
                                <div class="row_input_4">
                                    <strong class="total_price">Total:</strong>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row_input_4">
                                    <strong class="hint_holder iner">
                                        <a href="#" tabindex="-9999">Monthly Payment</a>
                                    </strong>
                                    <strong class="total_price" id="monthly_payment_result">
                                        $ 0                                    </strong>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row_input_4">
                                    <strong class="hint_holder">
                                        <a href="#" tabindex="-9999">Limit</a>
                                    </strong>
                                    <strong class="total_price" id="limit_result">
                                        $ 0                                    </strong>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row_input_4">
                                    <strong class="hint_holder">
                                        <a href="#" tabindex="-9999">Balance</a>
                                    </strong>
                                    <strong class="total_price" id="balance_result">
                                        $ 0                                    </strong>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="large-3 columns indent_top">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="large-15 columns box_bg_holder">
                <div class="indent_holder iner" style="padding-left: 0;">
                    <div class="large-9 columns">
                        <div class="row_label">
                            <label for="ApplicationLiability_comment">Income details (if any):</label>                        </div>
                        <div class="row_input">
                            <textarea class="textarea_box_2" name="ApplicationLiability[0][comment]" id="ApplicationLiability_0_comment"></textarea><span class="required_field_text" id="ApplicationLiability_comment_em_" style="display: none"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="large-3 columns"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="large-15 columns button_holder">
                <div class="indent_holder_2">
                    <strong class="btn_previous movePrev"><a href="#">Previous</a></strong>
                    <strong class="btn_save moveSave"><a href="#">Save</a></strong>
                    <strong class="btn_next moveNext"><a href="#">Next</a></strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    <input id="moveType" type="hidden" value="save" name="moveType">    </form>
```

With `event.preventDefault();` links does not work after clicking, without `event.preventDefault();` i can't see error message after validation and form is submitted but error message i can't see and page reload without notify user about errors.

If i am use this code for detect errors, form does'n submit and it not work.

```
$( "#"+where_it ).submit(function( event ) {
    alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
});
```

`where_it` 
this is id of form - work fine.

**UPDATE:** I want what form submit if is errors users notify about it, if not errors i am go to link.

**UPDATE1** When i am use this code

```
$( "#"+where_it ).submit(function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            if( /* no error */)
            {
               $( "#"+where_it ).submit(); 
            }else{
               alert( "error." );
            }
        });
```

I will have just redirect. Not submit form and not any errors. Handler for .submit() not work. This is strange.

**UPDATE2**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav_step ul li').on('click', function(event){
        $( "#"+where_it ).submit(function( event ) {
            alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );   
        });
        $( "#"+where_it ).submit();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

In this code works all. But if all good i am can't redirected after click event coz `event.preventDefault();` not allow it. If this is remove i can't see error message after validation. i think possible solution is do something this if success redirect(url: this .nav_step ul li a). But i don't know how do it.

Comment: fyi `live` is deprecated.

Comment: @Are you getting that alert msg?

Comment: As of jquery 1.7 `.live()` is deprecated. Use `$(document).on('click', '.nav_step ul li', function () {...});` instead

Comment: @DanielA.White He hasn't mentioned the jQuery version. If he is using old jquery version, `live()` should work.

Comment: I think im missing the point but theres no form in this html, and where the hell is where_it assigned/declared?

Comment: Form not missing, i am just not add her

Comment: I added a html form, but it does not matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `event.preventDefault()` but you should submit the form manually after everything was ok. `$( "#"+where_it ).submit();`.
something like this:

```
$('form').submit(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    if( /* no error */)
    {
       $('form').submit(); 
    }
});
```

[This is a simple demo you can check it out and change your code.](http://jsfiddle.net/Td5ag/1/)
**HTML**:

```
<form>
    <input type='text' id='name' name='name'>
    <input type='text' id='last_name' name='name'>
    <input type='submit' id='send' value='SEND'>    
</form>
<span></span>
```

**JS**:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event)
{
     event.preventDefault();
     if($('#name').val() != '' && $('#last_name').val() != '')
     {
         // here you can submit the form
         alert('submitted');
         //$('form').submit();
     }
     else
     {
         $('span').text('fill the textboxes.'); 
     }
});
```

Comment: @ArthurYakovlev check out the live demo

Comment: Trouble in not in live

Comment: @ArthurYakovlev for being live just you can use `on` event. like the above code.

Comment: Could you are look to UPDATE2 please?